# Dice Probability4

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Find the conditional probability of the event"The red one is 3, given that the sum is 6" when two fair dice (one green one red) are rolled. I got 1/6 but the answer key gives 1/5. How should I attack this one?

Answer (score 1):

There are more intuitive ways. But let $A$ be the event "red is $3$" and let $B$ be the event "sum is $6$." We want $\Pr(A|B)$. By the definition of conditional probability, we have
$$\Pr(A|B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}.$$
A standard counting argument shows that $\Pr(B)=\frac{5}{36}$. We get $A\cap B$ in only $1$ way, $3$ on red and $3$ on green. So $\Pr(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{36}$. Divide.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a,b)$ be the outcome of rolling both dice and $a\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is the Red die outcome and $b\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ the Green die outcome.

There are $5$ ways of obtaining a total of $6$:-

$$(1,5),(2,4),(3,3),(4,2),(5,1)$$

There is only one way of obtaining Red is $3$ given that the sum of both dice is $6$.

Therefore the probability that Red is $3$ given that the total was $6$ is $\frac{1}{5}$.